# What is the preferred way of storing a variable in GitLab without any collaborator ever seeing it?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I'd like to store a database connection string in a GitLab variable, so the GitLab CI/CD pipeline can set the project's configuration accordingly on deployment.

For security reasons, no-one in the team (except me) is supposed so ever see this connection string, not in the logs or anywhere.

How would I do that?

Comment: Excuse me if this is wrong - but isn't this exactly what 'secrets' are for? You don't get to see the actual information after you've entered it IIRC, not even you. In logs whenever a secret is parsed it blanks it out too.

Comment: @KamielDev: According to GitLab docs, secrets are either stored in the repository's `.gitlab-ci.yml` Actions file or in the project's properties section. Both can be read by developers and maintainers. In a highly confidential production environment, like, e.g., banking, none of these members are supposed to get access to any of these secrets.

Comment: When I go into a repository I am the sole maintainer of, and head over to the Settings>Security>Actions tab, I can only *update* or *delete* my secret variables. I can not see the contents at all, even if I wanted to. So no, I don't think they can be read by developers or maintainers. However, now that I think of it, any developers that has access to add new actions to your repo *could* theoretically write an action that, i.e., has a console command that e-mails them the contents of a secret, so I'm not sure if I would rely on that in a high-security setting like banking.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Gitlab SaaS, you can store variables as an admin under Admin → Settings → CI/CD → Variables.

No one can see these variables other than Gitlab admins.